# Excel not opening files intermittently

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel

We have a strange problem with Excel in the last couple of weeks, where files don't always open & it can take up to 6 attempts.  So far it's affected 3 PCs that I know of, all running Windows 11 and excel version 2210 Build 16.0.15726.20188 Click-to-Run 64-bit

We could attempt to open the file once & it will up fine or need to double-click it 6 times, it's very hit and miss and doesn't follow any pattern. Files can be local to the device, on Onedrive / Sharepoint or network shares - all are affected.
We have tried opening them in various ways, all have the same issue;

- Double-clicking on the file in explorer
- Right-click the file and clicking Open
- Clicking on pinned files when right clicking the icon on the task bar

I have tried a Quick Repair & then a Full Online Repair. Will try a full un-install / re-install now.

My own copy is also shouting about opening Excel in Safe Mode after I restart & my colleague could have 8 instances of Excel after multiple attempts to open a file.  This isn't happening on mine.

File associations are fine & it affects both .xls & .xlsx

I am assuming this is down to a recent Windows 11/ Office update.  Is anyone else experiencing this and any ideas on how I might resolve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the Windows and Excel versions different for the computer with problem and the computer without problems? If the issue only occurred after the update, and other factors did not change, it is most likely caused by the update.

Comment: I have same problem like you do you try to open blank sheet and try to close it (without any changes)? Same result? Do you have local domain or cloud domain or hybryd joint domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try to do an online repair for the applications in Control panel : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b
- Try to clear the cache of the apps : https://www.techsupportall.com/how-to-clear-cache-in-microsoft-office/

Try the method mentioned with office 365

- Use SARA tool and go through the steps: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/100607

Here are other things you can try and if they don't work, revert the settings :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/performance/office-applications-not-responding

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/administration/office-crash-or-cannot-start

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-not-responding-hangs-freezes-or-stops-working-37e7d3c9-9e84-40bf-a805-4ca6853a1ff4